# Can the fee be 10 times bigger than the amount that was sent?

Tags: transaction-fees

I don't understand one thing : If I get paid an amount of 0.000055 BTC ore more, how come the fee is 0.0005 ? The fee is ten times bigger than the amount I was paid?

Answer (score 3):

The tansaction fee is based mostly on the transaction size (in kilobytes), not its amount (in BTC).

Even more: the bitcoin protocol is quite unfriendly to small transactions to prevent spamming the network. If the transaction output is larger then 0.1 BTC, then the fee could be leveraged (more on fee generation algorithm [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_fees))

Answer (score 2):

This is to avoid Spamming transactions that would take a lot of space in the block chain.

If you want spend this coins you should wait until transaction fees will be decreased by future updates.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Similarly if you used a courier to send a package containing $0.01, you could find that it would cost more to send it then the value of the contents.